# PayPal Smart payment Button: Something went wrong. We'll take you back to checkout so you can try again

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I have tried to implement PayPal smart button from https://www.paypal.com/buttons/. In the end of the it shows **"Something went wrong. We'll take you back to checkout so you can try again"** error. I could not figure it out where I am making the mistake.

I have tested it with sandbox account - Success.

With live credentials it shows the error.

The code I am using is the very basic code provided from PayPal it self. You can check it out below.

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=[MY_LIVE_ID_HERE]&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',
          
      },
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                  amount: {
                      value: '1'
                  }
              }]
          });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
              alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
          });
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This error usually occurred when the billing information is not correct or the card details are not genuine. If you are getting this error on the sandbox account then please use that test credit/debit card details which are provided by PayPal with a valid test address.

Comment: I am getting error on live account. Sandbox testing was successful. I tried both debit card as well as credit card. Is there anything to with regions?

Comment: If you are getting the same issue continuously then please contact PayPal support. PayPal doesn't support credit/debit card payments in all regions due to some market restrictions. PayPal doesn't support debit/credit card payment in India.

Answer (score 1):

That is the only error that the black "Debit or Credit Card" button ever shows.  It will be shown in cases of normal declines. Live payments can be declined for very many possible reasons, for example if the card is refused, or if PayPal detects you are paying yourself which is not permitted.

---

(Sometimes the error will always happen as soon as the button is clicked, before the card fields are shown and before card details are entered. This usually means the receiving PayPal account is not able to receive card payments, perhaps due to the type of business. PayPal's customer service can advise on this.)

Comment: Yes you are right this is the problem with the black button. But I am sure that I was not paying my self. I tried with multiple cards, both credit and debit. Is there any thing to do with regions? I was using an Indian debit card and credit card.

Comment: Plenty of ways for those cards to be declined or for it to detect you are paying yourself

Comment: If that is true, then it would be a different reason for decline. Either is normal behavior and same message.